# Using or / || in Sunspot search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

How can I use 'or' in a Sunspot search?

In my code I have

```
with(:location_id, current_user.location.path_ids || current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids)
```

The search only evaluates the first part.

If I put 'current_user.location.path_ids' first (before ||), I only get the records resulting from that search. If I put 'current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids' first, I get the results from that search. I want the results of both.

I have also tried

```
with(:location_id, current_user.location.path_ids || :location_id, current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids)
```

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't used Sunspot, I think I can see the problem.

The `||` operator is logical OR so it is returning the left operand because it evaluates true.

I am assuming that `current_user.location.path_ids` and `current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids` are both arrays, therefore you will need to combine them with the `|` operator instead.

```
with(:location_id, current_user.location.path_ids | current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids)
```

Comment: Thank's! I found out that I also could just merge the two arrays with + instead of ||

Answer (score 2):

`||` is a Ruby operator. This code is basically evaluating the expression `current_user.location.path_ids || current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids` and passing that value as the second argument to the `with` method.

Check out the [Sunspot README](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme). I think you need `any_of`:

```
any_of do
  with(:location_id, current_user.location.path_ids)
  with(:location_id, current_user.location.parent.descendant_ids)
end
```

Comment: Thank's! I'll try to remember that one.